# Export to Word from PHP doesn't carry headers beyond first page

Tags: php, header, export-to-word

I exported data from a PHP page to a Word document but the header is not available in all pages.

Header is present in the first page but not in the other pages of the Word document.

Here is my code,

```
function changeDetails()
{
    $bType = $this->input->post('textvalue');
    if ($bType == "word")
    {
        $this->load->library('table');
        $data['countrytoword'] = $this->AddEditmodel1->export();
        $this->table->set_heading('Name','Country','State','Town');
        $out =  $this->table->generate($data['countrytoword']); 
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$cur_date.doc");
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo '<strong>CountryList</strong><br><br>';
        print_r($out);
    }
}
<? if(isset($countrytoword)) { ?>
  <table align="center" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Country</td>
      <td>State</td>
      <td>Town</td>
    </tr>
    <? foreach($countrytoword as $dsasffd) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbName'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbCountry']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbState']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbTown']; ?></td>
  <? } } ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: The code appears to generate HTML, not a word document. What library/framework are you using?

Comment: @outis i dont use any library and the code works fine for me the only problem is page header not coming after the first page....

Comment: then the sample is incomplete. What class is `changeDetails` a part of? What about the `load->library`, `AddEditmodel1->export` and `table->...` methods? When and how is `changeDetails` called? Which headers are you referring to, the table headers (which should use <th> elements, not <td>) or the HTTP headers (from the `header` functions)?

Comment: In any case, the sample code outputs a fragment of an HTML document, not a word document. If you want a word document, you'll need to write or find a library to output in that format, though I doubt you'll have much luck, since the MS Word Doc standard is closed. You can probably find a library to output RTF, which is readable by MS Word and many other editors.

Comment: you've got a: the `for` loop and `if` statement in the table generation code are ended too early. As a result, the generated row elements are missing their close tags, and the table close tag is output even if `$countrytoword` isn't set. For readabilities sake, you should use camelCase or separate_words_with_underscores.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the header row(s) with a <thead> element you should get what you want. So this code becomes

```
 <table align="center" border="0"> 
 <thead>
 <tr> 
  <td> 
   Name 
  </td> 
  <td> 
   Country 
  </td> 
  <td> 
   State 
  </td> 
  <td> 
   Town 
  </td> 

 </tr> 
 </thead>
```

Comment: <thead><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th></tr></thead> is the correct markup

Answer (score 1):

don't know about hearder but what kinda loop is this u r using

```
<? foreach($countrytoword as $dsasffd) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbName'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbCountry']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbState']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $dsasffd['dbTown']; ?></td>
  <? } } ?>
```

the TR tag is not closing(except last one) anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why Microsoft Word?

Now, two solutions:

1. If you name the file correctly, and set your MIME type correctly, you may be able to get MS Word to open the HTML file, just as you can from the desktop, when you use the **File → Open** dialog.
2. Another option is to generate LaTEX, then use latex2rtf to make RTF.   There are HTML to RTF converters, and RTF is simple enough that you could make it, but the LaTEX is easier to make than RTF and the quality seems to be better than HTML to RTF.
   Use a System call to run the application, naming the file using a UUID if the data is sensitive, and then redirect.  You would not even need to make the headers, as your web server should know what to do with an RTF already.